# html, css: display different span-text outside of <ul> for each ul li a, when hovered

Tags: css, visibility, html

OK, I have

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="page1.html" title="" class="small"><img class="large" src="img/image1.jpg" title="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html" title="" class="small"><img class="large" src="img/image2.jpg" title="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html" title="" class="small"><img class="large" src="img/image3.jpg" title="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Using css styles, the `menu` displays exactly one image of (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg) when one of links is hovered (all the rest have width=0px). Everything works perfect. The only thing I want is also to display some text (comment) to the image appeared on hover. Each image has a different comment. Each Comment is outside of the `<ul id="menu">`, it's displayed on another part of the page.
For example, for each image the spans are below:

```
<span class="span_ny">New York</span>
<span class="span_eu">Europe</span>
<span class="span_oo">Moon</span>
```

Spans are hidden, if links from the `menu` are not hovered.

How do I make `New York` text appear on the page if the first link is hovered? I would like the same for the second link `Europe` and likewise `Moon` as the third one.

I would prefer code with no jQuery, if possible.
I believe it is not possible to produce with css only, but that would be the most prefered method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS unless the comment elements are descendants of the anchors in the DOM tree (in which case you can selectively show one of them with `#menu a:hover span` or something similar).

This means that you only have two options really: either change the markup to bring the comments inside the list, or otherwise use Javascript/jQuery.

[Example fiddle that does this with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/p5YA6/).